# How to prove $P(\emptyset)=0$ from the axioms of probability?

Tags: probability, kolmogorov-axioms

A text states that you can prove that a probability of a null set is 0 through one of the axioms of probability. I know the three axioms, but I fail to employ these axioms to prove the above. I understand it only intuitively but would like a more formal explanation.

Comment: $1 = P(\Omega) = P(\Omega \cup \emptyset) = P(\Omega) + P(\emptyset)$ implies $P(\emptyset) = 0$ because $\Omega \cap \emptyset = \emptyset.$

Comment: @BruceET What a delightful coincidence! I just cracked open my first measure-theory primer today, just in time to see your comment and Dilip Sarwate's answer. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What are the axioms of probability  according to you or your textbook or instructor?

If your third axiom merely says

> If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive events, then $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$

then choosing $A = \Omega$ and $B = \emptyset$ suffices as in @BruceET's comment on your question. A more formal (pedantic?) approach might slip in the assertion that we know that $\Omega$ is an event, and so we have that $\Omega^c = \emptyset$ is also an event and so everything is kosher when we choose $\Omega$ and $\emptyset$ as our two events.

On the other hand, if your third axiom says

> If $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ is a countably infinite sequence of mutually exclusive events, then $$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i)$$

then you have to work a little harder. We will borrow the previous pedantry to prove that $\emptyset$ is an event and then take the countably infinite sequence of mutually exclusive events as $\Omega, \emptyset, \emptyset, \ldots$. This gives
$$P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) = P\left(A_1 \cup \bigcup_{i=2}^\infty A_i\right) = P\left(\Omega \cup \bigcup_{i=2}^\infty \emptyset\right) = 1 + \sum_{i=2}^\infty P(\emptyset).$$
But $\displaystyle \Omega \cup \bigcup_{i=2}^\infty \emptyset = \Omega$ and so we have shown that
$$1 = P(\Omega) = 1 + \sum_{i=2}^\infty P(\emptyset).$$
Can you take it from here to complete the proof that it must be the case that $P(\emptyset)=0$?

Comment: Do you really have to work harder? Isn't 2 events also a countable sequence

Comment: @CloseToC Yes, you do have to work harder because you have to deduce the finite additivity axiom from the countable infinite additivity axiom and before you can do that, it is necessary to prove that $P(\emptyset)=0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: (Usually?) texts define measures to additive on any countable collection of pairwise-disjoint sets, and a collection is countable if its index set is any subset of the natural numbers (e.g. finite or infinite).

Comment: @AlexR.  Yes, what you say is fine and dandy but while countably infinite additivity _implies_ finite additivity, the proof that this is true _requires, som where along the way, a proof that the empty set has probability $0$.